# Change css shape onclick

Tags: javascript, css-shapes

I have two shapes, a LINE and a CROSS. When I click the LINE it becomes a CROSS. All I want is to obtain a fluid shape transformation when I click.

LINE

```
#linea {
background: black;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
width: 2px;
}
```

CROSS

```
#cross {
background: black;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
width: 2px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#cross:after {
background: black;
content: "";
height: 2px;
left: -14px;
position: absolute;
top: 14px;
width:30px;
}
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE — https://jsfiddle.net/nk2w9w3z/3/

Thanks for any help.
F.

Comment: you haven't added the javascript.

Comment: it's added as external resource @jbutler483

Comment: Still, it's not working for me (on my chrome, anyway)

Comment: You'd need to actually alter the "line" element to become the cross (via css) in order to be able to use a css transition's on it. Currently your code is actually swapping the line element out for cross element entirely. You could for example position 2 lines on top of one another than simply rotate the two to make a cross (which could then be animated via the css transition property). Edit: see jbutler483's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should add a [`transition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) to your declaration.

> CSS Transitions allows property changes in CSS values to occur
>   smoothly over a specified duration.

For example;

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
div:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
div:hover:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>hover this gray box
```

To add this instead of a 'hover' (i.e. make it **clickable**), you could use a class styling instead, and toggle this with javascript/jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $('div').toggleClass("opened");
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.opened:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.opened:after {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>

click this gray box
```

**Note**

Prefixing the transform property would be [required for cross browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d). The [Transition property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) doesn't really need prefixing at all.

Comment: @FedericoFerrari: you need to add your vendor prefixes (safari requires transform to be prefixed with -webkit-). I have edited my answer to include these.

Comment: @FedericoFerrari: best way to thank someone is to accept their answer ;) (it's the tick to the left of their answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS transitions. You have a guide here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

You need something like `transition: all 1s;` in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```js
function changeShape(){
  var ele = document.getElementById("shape");
  (ele.className === "linea") ? ele.className = "cross" : ele.className = "linea";
}
```

```css
div{
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease; /* Firefox */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease; /* WebKit */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease; /* Standard */
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.linea {
background: black;
height: 30px;
position: relative;
width: 2px;}

.cross {
  background: black;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 2px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cross:after {
  background: black;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  left: -14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shape" class="linea"></div>
<button onclick="changeShape()">Change the shape</button>
```

Explanation:

What we do in the html part is easy. I create a "div" which initially is a "line" (note the class). Afterwards we've a button which is just a dummy to show how the code works.

Okay, on "onclick" we execute the changeShape() function. This function just changes the class from "cross" to "linea" or vice versa.

The most interesting part is the CSS. I've taken your two classes (the line and the cross) and added "transitions" to the div itself. The transitions make sure that you have this "smooth" tranformation into the different shapes. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp